# Slickgrid - how to do multiple column filtering

Tags: filter, filtering, slickgrid

I have a slickgrid that I am editing and I am baffled by how its filtering works. I want to be able to do multiple filtering using different textboxes and found the following examples:

http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html

And

http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-header-row.html

In each you can add additional filters which further refines the search. This second example is more in keeping of what I need however I still don't quite understand how the filtering works despite reading the wiki.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks